# How to bypass limit apikey drom tmdb?

Tags: php, api

Can I bypass limit apikey from themoviedb?
Because when my api get limit my site is get blank. 
I try to make more than 1 apikey with array

```
$apikey=array('api1','api2','api3','api4');
$i=array_rand($apikey);
$apikey = $apikey[$i];
```

But sometimes i still get blank page, my question is how to bypass limit?
I want when page is blank or apikey is limit then reload page with next apikey

Comment: Are you caching your data?

Comment: There is no limit attached to the API key, the limit is per IP number

Comment: yes not caching, if per IP number so array apikey is useless?

Answer (score 1):

From their site

```
Are there limitations on the number of requests?

We currently rate limit requests to 40 requests every 10 seconds. You can 
inspect the status of your limits by looking at the X-RateLimit response headers.
```

What this means is that you should be looking at the header `X-RateLimit` and slowing your requests.  4 requests a second should be significant enough for any automated task you are attempting.